# Laravel Livewire renders elements in list twice on production server

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, nginx, laravel-livewire

I have a very unusual problem with the display of li elements after the app has been uploaded to the production server.
In the local environment (docker) everything works fine.

This is my list in local enviroment

[image]

after the deploy to nginx on ubuntu my list looks like this

[image]

each element now occurs 2 times.

I've setted up the ubuntu server according to this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-laravel-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04

then optimazed the cache according to the laravel documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/deployment#nginx

I've also checked if the migration to mysql if the data appears twice in the database.

...but everthing is looking ok

[image]

snippet in liverwire component ArticlesList.php

```
public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.dashboard.articles-list', [
            'articles' => Article::query()
                ->search($this->search)
                ->producer($this->selectedProducer)
                ->filterBy($this->filter)
                ->orderBy('hcode')
                ->orderBy('style')
                ->paginate($this->perPage)
        ]);
    }
```

snippet in articles-list.blade.php view

```
<ul class="divide-y divide-gray-200">
            @forelse($articles as $article)
                <li wire:key="article-{{ $article->hcode }}.{{ $article->style }}" class="relative">

                    <div class="{{ $selectedArticleId === $article->id ? 'bg-blue-200' : 'hover:bg-gray-100' }} focus-within:ring-2 focus-within:ring-inset focus-within:ring-gray-500">
                        <div class="flex-1 min-w-0">
                            <a href="#" wire:click.prevent="selectedArticle({{ $article->id }})" class="block px-4 py-2 focus:outline-none">
                                <p class="block text-sm font-bold text-gray-800">
                                    {{ $article->fullStyle }}
                                </p>
                                <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 truncate">
                                    {{ $article->description }}
                                </p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
  @empty
    <li class="text-center">¯\_(ツ)_/¯</li>
  @endforelse
</ul>
```

wire:key is also setted to every li element:

[image]

I'm using Laravel v8.49 and Livewire ^2.5 on ubuntu 20.04, nginx 1.18 and php 8.0-fpm.

I really do not know any more and where the problem is.

Comment: It would help to see the actual code that generates that HTML, and the related query that it comes from (if applicable).

Comment: I have added the Laravel Livewire (view, component) code snipptes to my question.

Comment: Have you checked your database contents on the production server? Any chance you perhaps have duplicates in your database?